# Google s2 favicon retrieval doesn't work with subdomains

Tags: url, google-api, subdomain, favicon

I'm using Google's favicon retrieval url which works well unless using subdomains.

This works: https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=facebook.com

This doesn't https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=fortawesome.github.io

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That domain doesn't have a favicon at its [root](http://fortawesome.github.io/).

Since the s2 service does not support lookups for specific paths, there is nothing you can do.

(also note that this URL is not a public API, and there are no guarantees that it will continue to exist)

Comment: Thanks @SLaks. Any options besides the s2 service you know of that are more comprehensive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970570/use-google-favicon-but-dont-get-default-globe-when-no-favicon-exists

Comment: I really need a better service or a way to detect when googling is sending in the globe

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz When google sends a globe, its status code is 404, i.e. Not Found