# Use Google Favicon but Don't get default globe. when no Favicon exists

Tags: javascript, favicon

How can we check favicon provided by Google API is the default globe?

https://www.google.com/s2/u/0/favicons?domain=facebook.com returns the favicon of the facebook, where as https://www.google.com/s2/u/0/favicons?domain=anyRandomFakeDomain.io returns the globe as the favicon.

How can I (with JS in the browser ONLY) check if the favicon is default globe or not?

Answer (score 2):

Couple years late to the party, but anyway:

It seems if you request a bigger favicon size, i.e. add `sz=64` query parameter, existing favicons will be scaled to the size you requested but the default for non-existing favicon will always be 16x16

So you can load it in an image tag and check its size with js after its onload triggers.

This is of course relying on an undocumented (much like the api in general) feature which actually seems like a bug and may change at any time.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks! By simply checking for naturalHeight of the img to be not equal to 16 in onload listener

Comment: @emvaized I am facing a similar problem. Is there anyway you could share the code here please ?

Comment: You have to check `image.naturalHeight == 16`, which should return true only when it's default globe icon (while other images should get scaled to 64 by `sz=64` in url )